# How can I pass "this" into an action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a MainWindow class that extends JFrame and is the only frame in my application. I have several JPanels to change its content though. I would like to pass the MainWindow around so I won't have to make a global copy of it.

Here is the problem. I have a fake JMenuBar in MainWindow that I use to go around and look for screens. In their JMenuItem listeners, I cannot pass MainWindow as this to the JPanels.

Is there a way I can do that, like maybe marking the class final or do I have to create a new MainWindow each time I have to pass in one. It doesn't carry around any data so its not crucial and the performance isn't a major concern for a small final project like this but I want to know if there is a better way?

Comment: You presumably have a reference to a `MainWindow` object somewhere in your program. Just pass that to whatever class needs it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you unable to pass `this` because it would reference the listener? If so, you should be able to use `MainWindow.this`.

Or create a reference to `this` outside the listener and pass that as the parameter.

Comment: See also [*15.8.4. Qualified this*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4).

Comment: It worked, thanks. The reference to the listener was the exact problem. By it I mean, MainWindow.this

Answer (score 0):

Create the MainWindow class as the Outer class and extend this to JFrame which u already did, . Now in the MainWindow class, create as many inner classes as you want and let the handle the ActionListener method in different way..

eg:

```
  MainWindow extends JFrame {


    MainWindow(){



    }

    class panel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


    }


    class panel2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


    }




}
```

You can also implement Singleton Pattern, so that makes sure there is only one instance of MainWidow.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of this approaches:

- Make `MainWindow` singleton.
- Mark as `final` a variable in the method when you create the listener.
- Use `MainWindow.this`

For your case use the singleton approach, with that you can access freely from any place of your project.

Comment: 1+ for recommending use of `MainWindow.this`. 1- for recommending use of a singleton where one is most definitely not needed. So net vote is 0.